# LateInitializationError: Field 'mangaStatus' has not been initialized in flutter

Tags: android, database, firebase, flutter, dart

I create an application and I have this error.
I can take the status of the manga without any problems beacause when I print It It's work but when I refresh the app I have this error caused by my variable, if somoene can help I will be really greateful as always.

```
class DetailScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const DetailScreen({Key? key, required this.mangaImg, required this.mangaTitle, required this.mangalink}) : super(key: key);
  final String mangaImg,mangaTitle,mangalink;


  @override
  _DetailScreenState createState() => _DetailScreenState();
}

class _DetailScreenState extends State<DetailScreen> {
   late String mangaGenre,mangaStatus,mangaAuthor,mangaDesc;

  List<Map<String,dynamic>>? mangaDetail;
  List<Map<String,dynamic>>? mangaDescList;
  List<Map<String,dynamic>>? mangaChapters;

  void getMangaInfo() async {
    String TempBaseurl = widget.mangalink.split(".com")[0] + ".com";
    String TempRoute = widget.mangalink.split(".com")[1];
   final webscraper = WebScraper(TempBaseurl);
   if (await webscraper.loadWebPage(TempRoute)){
     mangaDetail = webscraper.getElement("div.panel-story-info > div.story-info-right > table > tbody > tr > td.table-value", []);

     mangaDescList = webscraper.getElement("div.panel-story-info > div.panel-story-info-description", []);

   }

   mangaGenre  = mangaDetail![3]['title'].toString().trim();
   mangaStatus = mangaDetail![2]['title'].toString().trim();
   mangaAuthor = mangaDetail![1]['title'].toString().trim();
   mangaDesc   = mangaDescList![0]['title'].toString().trim();


    print(mangaDesc);

  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    getMangaInfo();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size screensize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Constants.mygreen,
        title: Text(widget.mangaTitle),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: screensize.height,
        width: screensize.width,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              MangaInfo(
                mangaImg: widget.mangaImg,
                mangaStatus: mangaStatus,
                mangaAuthor : mangaAuthor,
              ),
```

Comment: Can you post the error too?

Comment: Your multiple `late` variables are initialized asynchronously.  There is nothing that prevents the `build` method from being called and attempting to use them before they're initialized.  Even worse, `getMangaInfo` doesn't return a `Future`, which prevents callers from waiting for it to complete.  Using `late` for variables initialized asynchronously is a recipe for `LateInitializationError`s.  Use nullable variables instead and check whether they're `null` first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error you posted in the comments, I'd suggest making the following changes.

Not initialising `late` fields will cause `LateInitializationError`s at runtime. As you mention in your comment, it's better to use nullable Strings (`String?`) instead of `late String`s to avoid this runtime error and handle potential null values explicitly:

```dart
// Change this:
late String mangaGenre,mangaStatus,mangaAuthor,mangaDesc;

// to this:
String? mangaGenre,mangaStatus,mangaAuthor,mangaDesc;
```

You're calling the `getMangaInfo()` method that's `async` but not waiting for it to return. It is possible that the `build` method gets invoked even before `getMangaInfo()` finishes:

```dart
// Change this:
void getMangaInfo() async {

// to this
Future<void> getMangaInfo() async {
```

```dart
// Change this:
getMangaInfo();

// to this
await getMangaInfo();
```

Now that `String ...`s have been changed to `String? ...`s, it's essential to assign fallback values in case the strings are `null`.

```dart
// Change this:
MangaInfo(
  mangaImg: widget.mangaImg,
  mangaStatus: mangaStatus,
  mangaAuthor : mangaAuthor,
),

// to this
MangaInfo(
  mangaImg: widget.mangaImg,
  mangaStatus: mangaStatus ?? "some-fallback-value",
  mangaAuthor : mangaAuthor ?? "some-fallback-value",
),
```

Comment: okay but basically I can't add an await on my void you know that ?

Comment: That's why `void` needs to be changed to `Future<void>`. Or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: I change everything like you  did and I don't have the same error but it send me the fallback value and I don't understand why

Comment: i think It's cuz flutter think that my manga status and my manga author are null but they're not